# How to properly drop a unique constraint on Django when migrating a OneToOneField to a ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I need to transform a OneToOneField in a ForeignKey, and obviously remove the unique constraint but makemigrations command can't identify that operation and it's not adding the RemoveConstraint operation.

How can I create the proper RemoveConstraint to the migrations file and make it safer to apply? I thought about getting the name of the constraint and hard coding it but I was thinking if there was a smarter way of doing this.

This is the generated migration file

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('acc', '0018_auto_20211113_2246'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='account',
            name='owner',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, related_name='accounts', to='acc.owner'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='account',
            name='internal_account',
            field=models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True, editable=False, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='historicalaccount',
            name='internal_account',
            field=models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=True, editable=False, null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: A RemoveConstraint operation shouldn't have to be explicitly added, when the AlterField operation is applied the constraint should be removed implicitly. Is the constraint not removed when applying this migration?

Comment: @IainShelvington It's giving me an error that I assumed that the migrations simply did not worked well. Now I'm not sure if I did something stupid and messed with the migrations. I'm getting the following error when running my test suite django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "acc_account_owner_id_706bf040" already exists

Comment: Is it possible that your test DB is in a bad state? Could you drop the test DB and try again?

Comment: Looks like that was the case. It was having problems only with the test database. I ran pytest with --create-db and things just worked.